# Do I need to serialize the abstract base class to make the derived classes serializable

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization

I am trying to store an object in Session variable, I have the class marked as serializable. This class however is derived from an abstract base class that is not serialized. I am getting an error. The problem is I do not get any error in development machine but only in production and staging area which I do not have access to. I didn't require to serialize the class to store the object to session in my dev machine but it gave serialization error in staging environment. So I marked the class as serializable and requested the deployment in staging environment. Now I am again getting the serialization error which says the base class is not marked serializable. Do I need to serialize the base class as well.

```
public abstract class A
{
    ///Properties
}
[Serializable]
public class B:A
{
      ///Properties
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as the exception suggests:

> Type 'A' in Assembly '...' is not marked as serializable

So to fix your problem - add a `[Serializable]` to class A too.

On the other hand, that attribute is not inherited, so if you would add it to A only, B would not be treated as Serializable.